# Unexpected, to me, return value from javascript in Robot Framework. Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, robotframework

When I execute this Javascript in Robot Framework

```
${locator}    Execute JavaScript    return document.activeElement
log  ${locator}
```

the log looks something like this:

```
KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log ${Locator}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20181120 12:14:37.008 / 20181120 12:14:37.008 / 00:00:00.000
12:14:37.008    INFO    <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b1f6da572666aa24004769a4ab3a2171", element="0.7758470428784936-13")>
```

However, when I execute the same code in the console of Chrome the result might look something like this:

```
input#login_field.form-control.input-block
```

Why does the RF/JS-combo return such a weird format/value? I need a CSS-id or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence this is what a WebElement object looks like. What Google does to represent that object value is to pick certain attributes that are human readable/recognizable and display those. There is (complex) logic behind this to show the unique CSS locator for a particular element.

An element is generally not used by Robot Framework but is can be. In the below example it is used instead of a locator:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary    
Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Get WebElement Name
    Open Browser     http://google.com        chrome
    ${WebElement}    Execute Javascript       return document.activeElement
    ${name}          Get Element Attribute    ${WebElement}    name
    Log    ${name}
```

Resulting in:

```
Starting test: Folder.Webdriver.Get WebElement Name
20181120 18:58:55.406 : INFO : Opening browser 'chrome' to base url 'http://google.com'.
20181120 18:58:59.499 : INFO : Executing JavaScript:
return document.activeElement
20181120 18:58:59.511 : INFO : ${WebElement} = <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c3648128649f6ffea907d36a6533e3fc", element="0.6417788615033906-1")>
20181120 18:58:59.527 : INFO : ${name} = q
20181120 18:58:59.527 : INFO : q
Ending test: Folder.Webdriver.Get WebElement Name
```

However the same could be achieved with only a small alteration of the javascript:

```
Get WebElement Name
    Open Browser     http://google.com        chrome
    ${name}    Execute Javascript       return document.activeElement.name
```